# File Manager/Browser path in Modx Evo

Tags: modx, modx-evolution

I've recently upgraded to Evo 1.0.15. It wasn't possible to do a DB backup and I did not build the original site so I am at a bit of a loss as to how it originally worked. Oh, and I'm not very familiar with ModX.

Anyway, everything works well, except that we now get a Page Not Found error in a popup window when trying to insert images.

The paths to File Manager and File Browser must somehow be wrong?

What is confusing me is that the directory tree is set up as

public_html

..modx

..uploads

and all the images, etc are in uploads/files and uploads/images.

Should they be under modx/assets/images?

All the directories in uploads have permissions of 0755

The individual Manager User paths are blank.

_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] is /home/masv/public_html

PHP Version 5.5.30

_SERVER["SERVER_SOFTWARE"] Apache

I've already tried pressing the "reset" buttons and flushed the cache.

Can anyone tell me what should I set the paths to? I'm referring to 
File Manager path 
File base path   and
File Browser URL

Answer (score 1):

Is the site running in the webroot or in a subfolder? It looks a bit like the second option, because otherwise the uploads folder won't be accessible from the web, but maybe the images in there are only hidden from the web and not directly accessible and shown only with a Plugin/Snippet inside of MODX.

The Evolution file browser would start in the `images` folder contained in the folder that is set by File Base Path setting (Tools -> Configuration -> File Browser). This setting defaults to `[(base_path)]assets/`. The File Browser URL below defaults to `assets/`. In most cases you have to change both values, to use different folders.

The File Manager Path setting (Tools -> Configuration -> File Manager) is responsible for the window shown with Elements -> Manage Files.

Comment: No, I think the site is installed in the web root. As in /public_html/modx 

I know about the stuff in paragraph #2, it's just that those default paths are still giving me a 404 not found when I try to insert an image or a file from the Edit Resource page.